# Check what administrator rights are needed by the application

Tags: windows, security, uac

Is there a tool that I can use to check why a certain application requires administrator rights under Windows7/Windows server 2008?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If application requires Admin right (UAC) on program startup - most likely this is set by developer in the application manifest.  This is described in the documentation under [UAC Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756945.aspx):

> `CreateProcess()` calls `AppCompat`, Fusion, and Installer Detection to assess if the application requires elevation. The executable is then inspected to determine its requestedExecutionLevel, which is stored in the executable's application manifest. The AppCompat database stores information for an application's application compatibility fix entries. Installer Detection detects setup executables.

Embedded manifests may be viewed by any PE resource browser. My choice - [Far Manager](http://farmanager.com/) & [ImpEx plugin](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/ImpEx) (I'm the author of ImpEx).

Search manifest for [requestedExecutionLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx) key.